# AngularJS refactoring methods onto Factories/Services

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, refactoring

I've been taking a stab at learning AngularJS lately, mildly succeeding at getting things to happen the way I want, and then I went back to refactor my code. I had this to start with:

```
window.App = angular.module('Plant', ['ngResource'])

App.factory 'Plant', ['$resource', ($resource) ->
  $resource '/api/plants'
]

App.controller 'PlantCtrl', ['$scope', 'Plant', ($scope, Plant) ->
  $scope.plants = Plant.query()

  $scope.totalCost = ->
    # code to sum up the #cost of all the plants

  $scope.addPlant = ->
    # code to create a new plant
]
```

Coming from a heavy Rails background, my first thought was to slim up the controller by moving the `totalCost` logic into the `Plant` factory. After all kinds of fiddling and endless reading about the difference between Services and Factories, The only working implementation I could find was:

- Leave the Factory alone
- Create a Service with all the model related methods I need
- Make the Factory available to the Service
- Make the Service available to the Controller

Here's the code:

```
App.factory 'Plant', ['$resource', ($resource) ->
  $resource '/api/plants'
]

App.service 'PlantService', ['Plant', (Plant) ->
  @all = ->
    Plant.query()

  @totalCost = (plants) ->
    # code to sum of #cost
]

App.controller 'PlantCtrl', ['$scope', 'PlantService', ($scope, PlantService) ->
  $scope.plants = PlantService.all()

  $scope.totalCost = ->
    PlantService.totalCost($scope.plants)

  $scope.addPlant = ->
    # code to create a new plant
]
```

Wasn't completely happy with this, but my controller was thinner and it'd had been way too long so I was ready to settle. I then realized I was using 1.0.6, and when I replaced my Angular files with the latest (1.2.7 at the time of writing), things stopped working, and I was shown the all too familiar `...has no method all()`.

If anyone has suggested refactorings, readings, or trolling insults on how I'm doing this all wrong - I'm all ears. Primary goal is to move model related logic out of my controller, on the hunt for the right implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I know off hand that have changed between those versions.  You now need to include ng-route.js separately and have your main module depend on ngRoute if you are using the built in routing.  Secondly if you're using ng-bind-html you'll need to change that to ng-bind and use $sce.trustAsHtml() on the string you plan to show in there.

For a more thorough check on changes go to the changelog here:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Check the breaking changes sections from 1.0.6 to 1.2.7 to find anything you might encounter in the upgrade.